# Creating a multi-coloured SVG that can be changed to a single colour based off metadata values - clipping masks?

Tags: inkscape, svg, fill, clipping-mask, metadata

I'm creating a business dashboard. The software I'm using can display SVGs that can change in colour depending on criteria set by the user, which it does by modifying the fill of whichever object in the SVG has it's metadata ID value set as "shape1" as shown below:

[image: In this example, the black circle will change colour]

In this example the black circle will change colour. But I'm trying to use this feature with images with multiple colours, for example the flag, which I would set to all white if that country wasn't selected by the user. I've tried using an SVG image and setting the ID value of the root group of the objects, and also using an imported png for the flag instead and changing image ID. I also tried adding a "fill" attribute to the flag image/group for which didn't work.

However, I did manage to accidentally create an SVG composed of 2 different coloured shapes which can become one block colour in the dashboard software as I desired. I think it was down to the "fill-rule" style attribute:

[image]

Here the black circle changes as expected and applies the changes to the rectangle too.
Is there any way I can get this to work with more complex shapes / non-svg images like the flag?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah just use clipping masks

Comment: Thanks, do you mind explaining in a bit more detail? This is my first time editing svgs

Comment: https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clipping-and-masking.html Anyway thats why its a comment not an answer